# Create Sequence only for flag N '

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to create a row number when flag='n' only Or I am okay to sort the data by flags and rank them.

For example:

```
+-----+-------+-------+
| ID  | Flag1 | Flag2 |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 100 | N     | N     |
| 100 | N     | N     |
| 100 | Y     | N     |
| 100 | N     | Y     |
| 101 | N     | N     |
| 101 | N     | Y     |
+-----+-------+-------+
```

Output:

```
+---------+-----+-------+-------+
| Seq_num | ID  | flag1 | flag2 |
+---------+-----+-------+-------+
|       1 | 100 | N     | N     |
|       2 | 100 | N     | N     |
|       3 | 100 | Y     | N     |
|       4 | 100 | N     | Y     |
|       1 | 101 | N     | N     |
|       2 | 101 | N     | Y     |
+---------+-----+-------+-------+
```

I have written a query using row_number() and partition by , but this does not check for flags. 
Basically, I need to first sort the data by flags. and if either of the flags or both are Y then sort them last. 
how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with `row_number()` and `partition by`; the following query should work:

```
declare @tmp table(ID int,  Flag1 char(1),   Flag2 char(1))
insert into @tmp values
     (100, 'N','N')
    ,(100, 'N','N')
    ,(100, 'Y','N')
    ,(100, 'N','Y')
    ,(101, 'N','N')
    ,(101, 'N','Y')

select row_number() over(partition by ID order by id, flag2, flag1) as Seq_num,
      ID,
      flag1,
      flag2 
from @tmp
```

Results:

[image]